# Perfect forwarding for methods of non-template classes

Tags: c++, c++11

Perfect forwarding is usually seen in the context of template classes. For a non-template class, is it worth making e.g. the constructor a template method so it can use perfect forwarding? Something like the below:

```
class Foo()
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        Foo(T &&vec) : memberVec(std::forward<T>(vec)) {};

    private:
        std::vector memberVec;
};
```

The advantages are fundamentally the same, but is anything different when we know the real class type? When would this be good practice and when not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-explicit one-argument ctor is a converting ctor.  Unless `Foo` should be convertible-from a vector (which might be true), you should make it `explicit`.

In general, with one-argument ctors you need to SFINAE-disable `Foo` types from being matched.  The implicit `Foo&&` and `Foo const&` ctors are worse matches when you invoke `Foo` with a `Foo&` (say, an non-const lvalue) than your template ctor.  A simple `class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>,Foo>>` suffices.

Slightly more code will be generated.

In this case, `std::vector<X>` is ridiculously cheap to move, so

```
Foo( std::vector<X> vec ):memberVec(std::move(vec)) {}
```

is 99% as efficient and clearer.

The usual perfect forwarding failures apply when you use it.  The above example doesn't have them -- I can `Foo x({1,2,3})` and it passes `{1,2,3}` to construct the `vec`.  With `T&&` it won't, because it cannot deduce what `T` is.

Comment: How would you know that the vector is cheap to copy? The vector could contain thousands X.

Comment: @vinc fixed.  Sorry copy/move typo.